# How to completely uninstall Dart and Flutter from Ubuntu?

Tags: googledart

I was trying to install Slidy, but with no success. Pub commands would not be recognized for nothing. So I decided to uninstall dart and flutter from my computer. Since I didn't found any tutorial on internet on how to remove flutter or dart, I just deleted dart directory from /usr/lib/dart and deleted my flutter installation directory. Now, every time I try to install dart, I get the following:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
dart is already the newest version (2.9.3-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

I tried sudo apt-get update, but nothing changed. Now I can't reinstall dart nor remove it completely from my computer. Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: Deleting files and directories that were placed by the package manager is very unwise, and makes a time-consuming mess. Next time, use the same package manager to uninstall software that the package manager installed.

Comment: Try `sudo apt install --reinstall dart` to clean up the mess. If it fails, add the complete output to your question above.

Answer (score 2):

Try sudo apt-get purge flutter

OR

sudo apt-get purge dart